# Macro button on Nikon L830 does not work

Tags: nikon, macro, camera-settings

I am fully aware of how to use the macro setting on my CoolPix L830. The button to turn it on does not work at all. Every other function on the camera works.

I tried resetting to factory defaults and that did nothing. Any suggestions?  I  think it needs to be professionally fixed. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: I'm curious - what is the button _supposed_ to do?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a L380, but the manual for it (the larger Reference Manual) is at http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive1/B6sUJ00pkWTy0186hYa00PAl9y53/L830RM_(En)02.pdf

Page 49 is "Using Macro Mode", and it says there if after selecting Macro, then if not pressing OK within a few seconds, this setting is ignored. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Also, it states that `The setting may not be available with some shooting modes.`